# Null-value when iterating through Hash key set

Tags: java, hashmap

It puzzles me how the following segment can lead to a null value of the Boolean mandatory, although it is not null at the corresponding key in the actual hashtable:

```
for (List<List<A>> a : hashMap.keySet()) {  
    Boolean mandatory = hashMap.get(a);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the actual value in the HashMap is not null?

Comment: A HashMap can have null values, but the bigger question is why is your key a List of Lists?  Couldn't you find a better key for your boolean value?

Comment: @rationalSpring: by inspecting the value in the debugger
@Paul no thats really what i need as keys

Comment: @user If you really need a List of Lists as a key to retrieve a bool then you really need to rework your code. Instead of doing something wonky like your code above why not make an object that has `List<A> a` and `boolean mandatory` as properties? You could then do something as simple as `myObj.isMandatory()` to get your value rather than populating a HashMap like you've done.

Comment: yes paul maybe you're right, i just dont like too introduce too many "struct"classes in my code

Comment: @user Too many "struct" classes?  That's what objects are, so you're saying you don't like too many objects in your code. Readability and maintainability are very important, and the fact that you're unable to successfully look up a boolean shows you need to consider those factors more than your aversion to objects.

Comment: What I meant was that I don't like too many classes without explicit meaning. Such classes just represent a relation.
But i refactored the code and it works fine now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HashMap will return `null` [if the key specified is not bound to a value](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29).

Issue is almost certainly that comparison op on `a` -- a List -- against keys is failing.

Let me guess: are you modifying these lists (the key object) after you have called a put?  Did you remove all entries in one of the keys?  Remember an empty list is `equal` to all empty ArrayLists.  Further remember that List.equals() compares list content (one by one) to test equality.

```
package sof_6462281;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Demonstrate the fact that the Map uses key.equals(k) to
 * test for key equality.  Further demonstrate that it is a 
 * very bad idea to use mutable collections are keys to maps.
 */
public class ListAsKey {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<List<A>, Boolean>  map = new HashMap<List<A>, Boolean>();

        List<A> alist = new ArrayList<A>();
        map.put(alist, true);
        for (List<A> a : map.keySet()) {
            Boolean b = map.get(a);
            System.out.format("\t%s(ArrayList@%d) => %s\n",a, a.hashCode(), map.get(a)); 
        }

        // you changed your list after the put, didn't you?
        alist.add(new A());
        for (List<A> a : map.keySet()) {
            Boolean b = map.get(a);
            System.out.format("\t%s(ArrayList@%d) => %s\n",a, a.hashCode(), map.get(a)); 
        }

        alist.clear();
        for (List<A> a : map.keySet()) {
            Boolean b = map.get(a);
            System.out.format("\t%s(ArrayList@%d) => %s\n",a, a.hashCode(), map.get(a)); 
        }
    }
    public static final class A { /* foo */ }
}
```

Results:

```
[](ArrayList@1) => true
[sof_6462281.ListAsKey$A@4b71bbc9](ArrayList@1265744872) => null
[](ArrayList@1) => true
```

edit: added more ops to above and added console out.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean can be null because it wraps the value-type primitive boolean.  I am unsure what you mean its not null at the corresponding key in the actual hashtable.  You are iterating over the keys then getting the values at those keys.  The value at a key was inserted as null so when you are retrieving it you are getting the null.

Comment: yes I understand, but the Boolean I inserted at the key is not null and i see it in the debugger too that the object is lets say true. but when i access it using the loop then i get a null value

Comment: You are going to have to provide more detail.  On a side note why aren't you just using the values() or entrySet() method to iterate over all the values or all the pairs in the hash map?

Answer (score 0):

Using a mutable object for a Map key is always a dangerous thing. If you maintain any reference to any of those keys after inserting into the map, then it is very likely that one of those keys will be modified at some point in the future which will invalidate the contents of your map.

A less likely, but possible scenario, even assuming you somehow don't screw up your `List<List<>>` key is if you have messed up the `equals` method of class `A`, then your Lists' `equals` method will also be messed up, again screwing up your map.

Look at alphazero's nice code example if you need further proof that what you are attempting to do is a bad idea.